# Find in array smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have an array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 32
        [type] => 4           
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 51
        [type] => 9            
    )
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
    ..
 [84] => Array
    (
        [id] => 51
        [type] => 9 
        [cnt] => 1180                       
    )   
 )
```

And i need to find value of **[cnt]** in my array, which lies only in one index of my entire array. The index of [cnt] is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over while array.

```
{foreach from=$data key='k' item='i'}
    {if $i.cnt == 1180}
        {assign var='key' value=$k}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Value 1180 is in key `{$key}`.

```
{$data[$key]|print_r}
```

If smarty has something like `break`, you can add it into `if` condition.

**EDIT:**
If you need to find value of `cnt`, it should be:

```
{foreach from=$data key='k' item='i'}
    {if isset($i.cnt)}
        CNT value is: {$i.cnt}
        Key of item with CNT: {$k}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: @Loura: okay, I've updated my answer. Inside foreach loop will be `isset`, the rest stays. You can write it inside a loop, assign to var, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_column` function of PHP as

```
$arr = array(  
           array('id'=>1,'value'=>'asdas'),     
           array('id'=>1,'value'=>'asdas'),  
           array('id'=>1,'value'=>'asdas'),  
           array('id'=>1,'value'=>'asdas'),  
           array('id'=>1,'value'=>'asdas','cnt'=>1185)  
        );  

print_r(array_column($arr, 'cnt'));
```